# C# changing a static method to not be static

Tags: c#, plugins, static

I'm fairly new to C# and very new to dealing with static classes/methods. I'm working on an application that used to be just a stand-alone and is now being converted to a plugin application. I have 1 plugin that is a global datasheet and another plugin that is a model that uses a copy of the global datasheet but can further manipulate it before running a model. 
So, I created a custom control called DatasheetControl. The global datasheet plugin and the Modeling plugin use an instance of the control. I'm fixing the bugs associated with going from a stand alone datasheet to having this control being accessed in 2 different plugins.
There is a class that the control uses for getting and setting the column information.

```
public class dtColumnInformation
{
    //table to operate with
    private DataTable _dt = null;
    //dictionary to hold column info
    private Dictionary<string, bool> dictColstatus = null;
    //class variable
    private static dtColumnInformation dtCI = null;

    // method initializes a datatable cols information structure to all enabled
    public dtColumnInformation(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt != null)
        {
            _dt = dt.Copy();
            dictColstatus = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

            for (int c = 0; c < _dt.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                dictColstatus.Add(_dt.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    // constructor optionally calls method to init the column information structure
    // and return the itself - singleton
    public static dtColumnInformation getdtCI(DataTable dt, bool init)
    {
        //pass null after initialization to access the DTcolInfo property
        //or pass init=true (after import) to initialize
        if (dtCI == null || init) dtCI = new dtColumnInformation(dt);
        return dtCI;
    }

    // method returns the enable/disable status of the column name (key)
    public bool getColStatus(string key)
    {
        //returns the status of a row
        bool boolStatus;
        dictColstatus.TryGetValue(key, out boolStatus);
        return boolStatus;
    }

    // method to set a table column to enable/disable
    public void setColStatus(string key, bool val)
    {
        //sets the status of a column
        dictColstatus[key] = val;
    }

    // property - structure to return column status of all columns in table...
    public Dictionary<string, bool> DTColInfo
    {
        //returns a col-status dictionary for all cols in the datatable
        set { dictColstatus = value; }
        get { return dictColstatus; }
    }
```

This is getting used in a few locations (including the global datasheet plugin) with the call similar to the following:

```
//(builds dictionary of keys, <string>datetime and values <bool>enabled/disabled col)
dsControl1.DTCI = VBCommon.Metadata.dtColumnInformation.getdtCI(dsControl1.DT, true);
```

So, I am beginning to understand why this isn't working. When I go back and forth between the global datasheet and the model, the dictColStatus isn't maintaining each's individual state. This comes into play when I right-click on a col heading and want to choose whether to enable a disabled col or disable it. The method for this function looks to see what's in the dictColStatus in order to decide what options to populate in the right-click menu.

I need to change the static stuff in this dtColumnInformation class to not be static so each instance of the control will be maintained. I know I need to do something with instantiating an instance of the dtColumnInformation class.. but the

```
private static dtColumnInformation dtCI = null;
```

and

```
public static dtColumnInformation getdtCI(DataTable dt, bool init)
```

are throwing me off. I'm not exactly clear what they are doing and how to make the changes throughout my classes to not use a static thing.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to C#! You might want to have a look at the .NET Guidelines for Names: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002

Answer (score 1):

getDtCI() is just an initializer that uses a single value cache. If the static field hasn't already been initialized, then it initializes it and returns the value in the static field.  If the init param passed in is true, then it will initialize a new value for the static field and return that.  The previous value of the static field is thrown away. Multiple calls to getdtCI() with init=false will return the same dtColumnInformation instance. This single value cache might be an effort to conserve memory for something that gets requested a lot and/or that is expensive to construct.

If you want to have multiple containers with independent dtColumnInformation objects, you will have to change this in some fashion.  The simplest approach is to eliminate the single item cache entirely - change getdtCI() to always create a new instance of dtColumnInformation.  View references to getdtCI() to survey the code impact. If constructing a dtColumnInformation doesn't take an enormous amount of time or memory, and the code isn't calling getdtCI() millions of times, then you can probably get by with eliminating the static cache completely and always construct new instances of dtColumnInformation.

If always constructing a new dtColumnInformation takes too much time or does consume a lot of memory, you could perhaps move the single item cache storage location out of the dtColumnInformation class into the container class that uses dtColumnInformation instances. Perhaps that is your DatasheetControl. The most direct way to do that is to move the static field and the getdtCI() static method to the container class.

If you run into code which calls getdtCI() which does not have access to the container class, you'll have trouble using this simple solution. It gets really ugly beyond this point. :P